# What does 未鑑定の為、模写として出品致します mean?

Tags: translation, meaning

The description says

> 未鑑定の為、模写として出品致します。

Does it mean the artwork being auctioned is not authentic and only a copy or does it mean because it is not identified the owner can not guarantee the authenticity?

Answer (score 4):

> 未鑑定の為、模写として出品致します。

It says "Because it hasn't been identified by an expert, I'm putting it up for the auction as a copy."

> Does it mean the artwork being auctioned is not authentic and only a copy or does it mean because it is not identified the owner can not guarantee the authenticity?

So I'd say it's the latter, rather than the former. (They're not saying it's a copy, but that they're submitting it as a copy.)